# Is it possible to take advantage of FP16 for mining BTC or ALTs?

Tags: mining-theory, altcoin, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

I know mining uses mostly Integers, not Floating Point Ops... but still, is it possible to use Graphics Cards that support native 16bit Math for mining? Will it improve the performance in specific Algorithms?

My point is, you have DOUBLE the GFLOPS in FP16 compared to FP32, so..... computationally wise it is debatable....

Answer (score 1):

No l, floating point operation are pointless, regardless of how fast they are or what precision they have.

Also, BTC is mined using ASICs since 5 years ago or so, using a GPU is a waste of time and money.

Comment: I know about the ASICs, my question was about ALTs too, but further research from me and i noticed that in fact using Floats could change the HASH outputs when you use different precision, simply because 0.5 is a different number then 0.5001 for example!